# eth.balance() shows random alphanumeric content

Tags: dapps, ethereumjs, ethjs

```
const HttpProvider = require('ethjs-provider-http');
const Eth = require('ethjs-query');
const eth = new Eth(new HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/'));

eth.getBalance("0x39af04b02299c88b76d30a6d1db1b98368dafa26", 
        function(err, res){
            console.log(res,err);
        });
```

This ( " 38d7ea4c68000 " ) is what it returns , but i have  0.001 ether in that address

Comment: Please mark the answer as right if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

38d7ea4c68000 in hexadecimal is 1000000000000000 in decimal, which is 0.001 ether.